# Three.js - Is FlatShading implemented for BufferGeometry

Tags: three.js, webgl

It seems that setting `THREE.FlatShading` for a material doesn't work for `BufferGeometry`. Is it implemented?

I'm creating `BufferGeometry` with `CTMLoader (useBuffers = true)` and applying either `MeshLambertMaterial` or `MeshNormalMaterial` with `shading: THREE.FlatShading`. 
Three.js still renders everything as SmoothShading.

If I switch to ClassicGeometry (useBuffers = false), everything works as expected. Unfortunately, that would not work for us since our models are huge and that was exactly the reason to use `BufferGeometry`.

Is it just not implemented or is it very difficult/time-consuming/not-possible to implement?

Thank you in advance for any hints or suggestions. I'm using the latest r58 version.

P.S.

I found a recent Ryan Rix' post on the same topic http://rix.si/2013/04/15/threejs-ctm-and-you/ where he had to switch to ClassicGeometry to make it work.

Comment: It's not implemented in r.58. As an experiment, before rendering, try calling `BufferGeometry.computeVertexNormals()` and see if it results in flat-shading. This will, of course, overwrite your existing vertex normals.

Comment: @WestLangley, thanks, I tried - doesn't work. Also setting dynamic=true didn't help either.

Answer (score 0):

In three.js **r73** flat shading is working with `THREE.MeshPhongMaterial` for sure. You can use it like this:

```
geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();

//... make your geometry

material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ 
    color: 0xff0000, 
    shading: THREE.FlatShading
});

mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
```

This doesn't work for `THREE.MeshLambertMaterial` yet. But they are working on it. Check the related issue [here on GitHUB](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/7130).

Answer (score 0):

flatShading does work in MeshPhongMaterial or any other, the property for
flatShading is boolean
flatShading : Boolean
Define whether the material is rendered with flat shading. Default is false.

```
const PlaneMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color:'blue',
side:THREE.DoubleSide,
flatShading:true})
```

[Code Snipet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71SFg.png)